# Laravel Eloquent. Одна модель, имеющая два внешних ключа на две другие модели

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Имеются следующие 3 миграции с такими полями:

**Кафедры:**

```
class CreateDepartmentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('institute_id');
            $table->foreign('inst_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('institutes')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('departments');
    }
}
```

**Должности:**

```
    class CreateDegreesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('degrees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('degrees');
    }
}
```

**Преподаватели:**

```
    class CreateLecturersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lecturers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('middle_name');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->bigInteger('department_id');
            $table->foreign('department_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('departments')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('degree_id');
            $table->foreign('degree_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('degrees')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unique(['last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('lecturers');
    }
}
```

Таблица с *преподавателями* имеет 2 внешних ключа, которые ссылаются на *должности* и *кафедры*, а именно *degree_id* и *department_id*. Т.е. на одной кафедре и одной должности может быть много преподавателей, а один преподаватель может принадлежать только одной кафедре И только одной должности. Не совсем понятен тот момент, как построить между моделями отношения: два belongsTo() в модели Lecturer или использовать полиморфное отношение? Если я, например, захочу показать в таблице ФИО преподавателей, их должности и кафедры (получить названия должностей и кафедр по внешним ключам), то как мне поступить в такой ситуации? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Описание моделей в случае отношения один ко многим:

**Кафедры:**

```
class Department extends Model
{
    public function institutes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Institute');
    }

    public function lecturers(){
        return $this->hasMany('Lecturer');
    }
}
```

**Должности:**

```
class Degree extends Model

    {
        public function lecturers(){
            return $this->hasMany('Lecturer');
        }
    }
```

**Преподаватели:**

```
class Lecturer extends Model
{
    public function departments(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Department');
    }

    public function degrees(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Degree');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) У вас ошибка в миграции. Ключ должен ссылаться на  `institute_id`

```
$table->bigInteger('institute_id');
$table->foreign('inst_id')
```

2) Почему у вас `id` - `bigInteger`? Для `id` - лучше использовать `unsignedInteger`

3) Здесь никакой полиморфной связи не наблюдается

Модели у Вас описаны корректно. Только названия `relation` должны быть в единственном числе для преподавателя - так как он может иметь только одну кафедру и только одну должность.

Запрос будет примерно такой

```
Lecturer::with('degree','department')->get();
```

Ответ будет вида:

```
[
  0 => [
      name => 'John',
      ...
      degree => Degree(Model),
      department => Department(Model)
   ],
   1 => [
     name => 'Brian',
      ...
     degree => Degree(Model),
     department => Department(Model)
   ]
]
```